# How to use function from one custom module in another custom module

Tags: node.js

I have a following project structure

```
|server
|- module1.js
|- module2.js
|app.js
```

**module1.js** looks this way

```
module.exports = {
    f1 : function(){ ... },
    ...
    fN : function(){ ... }
};
```

**module2.js** looks this way

```
module.exports = {
    t1 : function(){ ... }, 
    ...
    tN : function(){ ... }
};
```

In app.js I use both of these modules

```
var M1 = require('./module1.js');
var M2 = require('./module2.js');
```

So right now I can use `M1.f1()`, `M2.t1()`. The problem is that in module2 I have to use functions from module1. If I define t1 as function(){ M2.f1(); .... } it generates an error telling that M2 is not defined.

How can I fix it? (I know that I can require module2 in module1, but it just doesn't feel right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Require `M1` in `M2`.  Not sure why you don't think it "feels right" but it's a legitimate way to handle it.

2) After you declare `M1 - require('./module1.js');`, pass `M1` into `M2` so it can be used in `M2`.  This will give you access to the properties there.  You'd wind up with something looking like `var M2 = require('./module2.js')(M1)`.  In my opinion, this starts to complicate things more than the require in #1...

3) If you want the same function in both...then maybe you need a third module.  This third module would export the functions that both `M1` and `M2` will expose as methods.

This third way is probably the best if you find yourself with a bunch of commonly used functions that aren't tightly coupled to one or another object.  Creating a utility module that exports these common functions (file or database functions are examples) for reuse in others is a common approach.

Note that you'd wind up requiring this third module in both of the original two...which I think is reasonable given the way the code would be organized so that you were requiring a 'utility library' that is used by the other two modules.

Answer (score 1):

The other option (besides requiring module1 in module2) would be to pass the functions in to module2:

```
// module2.js
module.exports = function(mod1) {
  // use mod1.f1, ..., mod1.fN anywhere in here
  return {
    t1 : function(){ ... },
    tN : function(){ ... }
  };
};

// main.js
var M1 = require('./module1.js');
var M2 = require('./module2.js')(M1);
```